# How to host multiple WebSites on same IP and Port in IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-deployment

I'm working asp.net web based application, I have deployed this application on server, Its getting response on port 80 from a outside client. I want the to fix the bugs so I want to run this application in Debug mode so that I can attach the worker process with the application and this is making the Performance down and its disturbing the QA team. So can I have two application one can run in release mode so that QA activity does not get disturbed and parallelly I can debug the build and fix the bugs or can do further development. I'm facing the same problem during the development activity, If multiple developers are working paralley , only one is able to debug the application other one has to wait. So please suggest me, If I can get rid of this situation.

I have only one server on which I can test this application.

So My requirement is how to host multiple websites on single ip and port.

Comment: why don't you create another site with same applications(debug mode) deployed on it? Let QA work on their env.

Comment: Issue comes from Production Site and There are other applications also which are interacting with same DataBase.